# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map) started returning null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a map fragment inside another fragment. This was working before, but I think it messed up after I updated google play services library. What is wrong?
fragment_map.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MapFragment:

```
GoogleMap map;
private static View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap(); // NullPointerException at this line
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had to change

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

to

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

to get it working. No idea why it was working perfectly few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

[This is the answer:](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView, you should not be doing this. Use the suggested method in official documentation for inter-fragment communication. Here, I think your issue is timing related. Not all fragments are created or managed synchronously. Also, I am not very sure if you can call getActivity() from onCreateView() - because fragments will get onActivityCreated() callback only after onCreateView().